# Ошибка подключения к бд Oracle (the network adapter could not establish the connection)

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Не получается подконектиться к бд.  В `SQL Developer` выдает ошибку `the network adapter could not establish the connection`
По команде `lsnrctl status` выдает следующее. Еще вчера все работало. После того как админ накатил образ на тестовую машину перестало подключаться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам файл `listener.ora`

```
    # listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.


LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = app-01test.XXXX.ru)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

Comment: Обратитесь к админу. Помсотрите логи.

Comment: @0xdb папка логов по пути C:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log пустая

Comment: А что админ сказал?

Comment: БД установлена на этой же машине? Пинг проходиит? Добавте больше информации в вопрос, пока на него невозможно ответить.

Comment: @0xdb пинг проходит . БД установлена на удалённой машине . Я просто не знаю какие детали ещё описать .  Может какие то службы у меня не запрещены ?

Comment: То есть, и листенер на удалённой машине. А что вы тогда смотрите на локальной машине?

Comment: @0xdb а разве листенер не нужно настраивать на клиентской машине?

Comment: У вас настроен прокси листенер?

Comment: _разве листенер не нужно настраивать на клиентской машине_, листенер входит в поставку БД, это ни клиентеская программа.

Comment: Вы не ответиили на вопос - _админ накатил образ на тестовую машину перестало подключаться_, и где виновник? Или в вашей организации это нормально?

Comment: Попробуйте tnsping <connect parameters>, он как раз  листенер проверяет.

Comment: @0xdb к сожалению с админом общаемся по почте , телефону .только в понедельник смогу с ним связаться . Но я на своей стороне ничего не менял . Спасибо за ответы !

Comment: _Но я на своей стороне ничего не менял_, это понятно, у вас что-то с сетевым соединением с сервером БД, вы врядли без админа сможете с этим разобраться.